# WP8 ListPicker Bind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

When I bind my data via item source to my `ListPicker`:

C#:

```
var sightingTypes = SightingTypes.List;
sightingTypesPicker.ItemsSource = sightingTypes;
```

XML:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="sightingTypesPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding sightingTypes, ElementName=this}">
        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I can see the Name being shown in the ListPicker, but, when I click on the ListPicker it shows the List of the Object Type, like this:

```
MyProject.Model.SightingType
MyProject.Model.SightingType
MyProject.Model.SightingType
MyProject.Model.SightingType
MyProject.Model.SightingType
MyProject.Model.SightingType
```

How do I:

A: Make the `Name` Property show when the list shows

B: Bind the `ID` Property as the Value but not show it

Comment: Why are you assigning ItemsSource twice, once in code and once in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign `FullModeItemTemplate` for that to work:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="sightingTypesPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding sightingTypes, ElementName=this}">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeOtherProp}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

**EDIT**: To answer your question B: You can use the SelectedItem DependencyProperty to get the instance of the selected object:

With MVVM approach:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="sightingTypesPicker" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SightingTypes}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSigntingType, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

With code-behind approach:

```
sightingTypesPicker.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => {
    MessageBox.Show(((SightingType)e.AddedItems[0]).ID);
};
```