# ListPicker Binding Items - Selected Item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, binding, windows-phone, listpicker

In my Windows Phone app, I have a ListPicker. This ListPicker is populated from a collection.
The data is loaded correctly, but the text is wrongly displayed. I do not know why...
Follow the images for understanding (the error is red marked):

XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Picker" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    FullModeHeader="Selecione o vendedor:"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding funcionarioVendedor}"
                     Margin="135,186,35,313" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,20" Text="{Binding nome}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<vendedores> funcionarioVendedor { get; set; }

    public class vendedores
    {
        public string nome { get; set; }
    }

var myData = e.Result;

            var reader = new StringReader(myData);
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // String JSON
            string json = text;

            // Parse JObject
            JArray jObj = JArray.Parse(json);

            funcionarioVendedor = new ObservableCollection<vendedores>(
 jObj.Children().Select(jo => jo.ToObject<vendedores>()));

            Picker.ItemsSource = funcionarioVendedor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only setting the `FullModeItemTemplate`. The template used for the selected item is the one specified with the `ItemTemplate` property, so you have to set it as well.

Comment: Nice! You save my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Within your `ItemsSource="{Binding funcionarioVendedor}", try adding this too:

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding funcionarioVendedor, ElementName=this}"
```

Reference: [WP8 ListPicker Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301957/)

[Binding ListPicker to Data](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WindowsPhone/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/ListPicker_Binding_to_Data.html)